# How do I get a comma-separated value from my user table?

Tags: mysql

My user table:

[image: http://awesomescreenshot.com/01c3trgfad]

I used the below query to get my expected result:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT (count(user_id) SEPARATOR ',') 
   FROM userinfo 
 GROUP BY date(Reg_Date)
```

but it shows me this error:

> "Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'SEPARATOR ',') FROM userinfo GROUP BY Reg_Date' at line 1"

My expected result is **1,4,1**

Comment: remove the `count` in `group_concat`

Comment: ok, but i need to count user as their reg_date

Comment: then add a `count(*)` something as `select date(Reg_Date),count(*),GROUP_CONCAT (user_id) FROM userinfo GROUP BY date(Reg_Date)`

Comment: It throw me this error
"Error in query (1630): FUNCTION radius.GROUP_CONCAT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual"

Comment: Are you writing a stored procedure or something I am quite not sure `group_concat` is a standard aggregate function in mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to get a the count of users for each date, but in a single comma seaprated list?

If so try:-

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_count SEPARATOR ',')
FROM
(
    SELECT count(user_id) AS user_count
    FROM userinfo 
    GROUP BY date(Reg_Date)
) sub0
```

Comment: Yes, Its working, but i have one question sir. why you use "sub0"? I dont understand, please give me explain if you have time
Thanks :)

Comment: It is just a sub query (which is getting the count of users for each day). But sub queries like this must have an alias name. I just tend to use sub0, sub1, etc, as an alias for sub queries when there is no meaningful name I can think I in the situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Some times I just feel envy, why I'm not so much knowledgeable like you guys :)
Thanks again, have good time :)

Answer (score 1):

It is just a typo, do not user whitespace in the query between the called function and the parameters:

```
SELECT COUNT(User_id), GROUP_CONCAT(user_id SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM userinfo GROUP BY date(Reg_Date);
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dea2/4/0